# OrientDB ETL with CSV, no headers and multiple join fields

Tags: etl, orientdb

I am trying to load some CSV files into OrientDB.  They have been extracted from a MySQL database holding the Unified Medical Language System (NIH UMLS) data. The two files contain vertices:

```
"C0484850"  "A18164418" "Troponin T.cardiac [Mass/volume] in Venous blood"  "Y" "Clinical Attribute"
"C0484850"  "A18241423" "Troponin T.cardiac:MCnc:Pt:BldV:Qn"    "Y" "Clinical Attribute"
"C0484850"  "A18861342" "Troponin T.cardiac:Mass Concentration:Point in time:Blood venous:Quantitative" "Y" "Clinical Attribute"
"C0484851"  "A18280127" "Troponin T.cardiac [Mass/volume] in Serum or Plasma"   "Y" "Clinical Attribute"
"C0484851"  "A18357585" "Troponin T.cardiac:MCnc:Pt:Ser/Plas:Qn"    "Y" "Clinical Attribute"
"C0484851"  "A18816754" "Troponin T.cardiac:Mass Concentration:Point in time:Serum/Plasma:Quantitative" "Y" "Clinical Attribute"
```

and relationships:

```
"C0484850"  "A18164418" "has_common_name"   "C0484850"  "A18241423"
"C0484850"  "A18241423" "class_of"  "C0201682"  "A18205079"
"C0484850"  "A18241423" "component_of"  "C3538889"  "A18284809"
"C0484850"  "A18241423" "property_of"   "C0560150"  "A18367132"
"C0484850"  "A18241423" "scale_of"  "C1442116"  "A18405933"
"C0484850"  "A18241423" "system_of" "C1442207"  "A18136032"
"C0484850"  "A18241423" "time_aspect_of"    "C1442880"  "A18406936"
"C0484850"  "A18241423" "fragments_for_synonyms_of" "C2603360"  "A18401194"
```

I'm finding the OrientDB documentation [for extractors](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/orientdb-etl.wiki/Extractor.html) and [for CSV](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb-etl.wiki/Import-from-CSV-to-a-Graph.html) rather lacking.

1. For the "row" extractor, there is only one example with no full documentation.  I do not have row headers, so how to I use the "row" extractor to name the fields in the vertices (cui, aui, description, pref, syn) ?  I'm guessing there is a syntax like id:row[2](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb-etl.wiki/Import-from-CSV-to-a-Graph.html) but I can't find it.
2. The edges are joined using via the 2 and 5th fields of the vertices, which are unnamed.  Also, the edge property is unnamed.

For silly reason, I can't pull directly from MySQL right now, but if there are better examples than the official site I would be interested in seeing them.

Answer (score 1):

use the csv extractor (see : http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Extractor.html ) 
set "columnsOnFirstLine" to false
set "columns" to be the explicit list of columns, in the order they exist in the csv file